# Android: Using fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Is it possible to disable an activity elements when it loads a fragments?
I have a program which has an activity and two fragments. I put a container in activity. When I put two buttons in activity and load each fragment by clicking the button, fragment loads on the activity, but when I click in the position of buttons which are under fragment(or in the large screen next to it), they do some actions, however I don't like it. The buttons should not be clickable.

As a simple solution I create a third fragment and put my buttons in it and load it as a default view in the activity.

I was wondering is it possible to do this without using third fragment.

Comment: button.setClickable(false); after fragment transition commited.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want clicks to propagate to below layers you can specify [`android:clickable="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable).

In your case define `android:clickable="true"` in the bottom layout of your fragments layout xml file to stop any clicks to the activity below.

Answer (score 0):

mach's solution is great, but i can suggest a solution that will be helpful if you want to do more actions in the future than just disabling buttons.

You can simply have your activity implement an Interface "OnFragmentLoaded" for example which has a single method onLoaded()

and in your fragment in your onAttach(Activity ac) method you can do the following

```
((OnFragmentLoaded) ac).onLoaded()
```

and you activity would implement onLoaded() to do what ever you want